# Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

My code:

```
let AuthUser = data => {
  return google.login(data.username, data.password).then(token => { return token } )
}
```

And when i try to run something like this:

```
let userToken = AuthUser(data)
console.log(userToken)
```

I'm getting:

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

But why?

My main goal is to get token from `google.login(data.username, data.password)` which returns a promise, into a variable. And only then preform some actions.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix , see this article: https://medium.com/@bluepnume/learn-about-promises-before-you-start-using-async-await-eb148164a9c8#.w234uo7h3

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix look at `getFirstUser` function

Comment: So what about it? It's a function returning a promise.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix so you mean even in that example we need to use then to access the data promise returning in getFirstUser function?

Comment: In that exemple yes, the only other way is to use the ES7 syntax "await" that seems to resolve stop the execution of the current context to await the result of the promise. If you read the article you'll see it.  But since ES7 is probably almost supported nowhere yet, yes. The "then" is pretty much it.

Comment: @LoïcFaure-Lacroix Thank you. I know about await, but since i want to run script without babel, i decided to use Promises to avoid callback hell. But it seems to me, that i'm close to 'then hell' :D ... so, there are 0 way to use  promises and get result of a promise into a variable and only then continue execution?

Comment: No there is no way as far as I know as code is executed in a different context.

Comment: Technically, even with `await` it only pauses the execution inside a function (co-routine style). You can't await outside a function and the function you await in you need to mark as `async` and that function will return a promise instead. In the end, you cannot escape using callbacks when dealing with async code.

Comment: @slebetman async/await allows you to get return value of a promise and place it in the variable. That's how you escaping callback.

Comment: @Src: Yes, but only inside the async function. If you need the value in the main loop of your program you still need to pass a callback to the promise that the async function returns.

Answer (score 393, accepted):

The promise will always log pending as long as its results are not resolved yet. You must call `.then` on the promise to capture the results regardless of the promise state (resolved or still pending):

```
let AuthUser = function(data) {
  return google.login(data.username, data.password).then(token => { return token } )
}

let userToken = AuthUser(data)
console.log(userToken) // Promise { <pending> }

userToken.then(function(result) {
   console.log(result) // "Some User token"
})
```

Why is that?

Promises are forward direction only; You can only resolve them once. The resolved value of a `Promise` is passed to its `.then` or `.catch` methods.

## Details

According to the Promises/A+ spec:

> The promise resolution procedure is an abstract operation taking as
>   input a promise and a value, which we denote as [[Resolve]](promise,
>   x). If x is a thenable, it attempts to make promise adopt the state of
>   x, under the assumption that x behaves at least somewhat like a
>   promise. Otherwise, it fulfills promise with the value x.
>
> This treatment of thenables allows promise implementations to
>   interoperate, as long as they expose a Promises/A+-compliant then
>   method. It also allows Promises/A+ implementations to “assimilate”
>   nonconformant implementations with reasonable then methods.

This spec is a little hard to parse, so let's break it down. The rule is:

If the function in the `.then` handler returns a value, then the `Promise` resolves with that value. If the handler returns another `Promise`, then the original `Promise` resolves with the resolved value of the chained `Promise`. The next `.then` handler will always contain the resolved value of the chained promise returned in the preceding `.then`.

The way it actually works is described below in more detail:

**1. The return of the `.then` function will be the resolved value of the promise.**

```
function initPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    res("initResolve");
  })
}

initPromise()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // "initResolve"
    return "normalReturn";
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // "normalReturn"
  });
```

**2. If the `.then` function returns a `Promise`, then the resolved value of that chained promise is passed to the following `.then`.**

```
function initPromise() {
  return new Promise(function(res, rej) {
    res("initResolve");
  })
}

initPromise()
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // "initResolve"
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
       setTimeout(function() {
          resolve("secondPromise");
       }, 1000)
    })
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    console.log(result); // "secondPromise"
  });
```

Comment: Your first one is not working. `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .`. The second one needs a return for `Promise`

Comment: @zamil you have to invoke the function, like in the second example. you cant `.then` on a uninvoked function. updated the answer

Comment: I'm bookmarking this so that I can keep it **forever.** I have been working a VERY long time to find truly clear and readable rules of how to actually build promises. Your blockquote of Promises/A+ spec is a perfect example of why it's been a PITA to self teach promises. It's also the ONLY time I've seen setTimeout used where it didn't confuse the lesson itself. And excellent reference, thank you.

Comment: it does not work while assigning the result to another variable.

Comment: it still returns Promise { <Pending> }

Answer (score 67):

I ran into the same issue and the answer for the problem is since ES2017, that you can simply `await` the functions return value (as of now, only works in `async` functions), like:

```
let AuthUser = function(data) {
  return google.login(data.username, data.password)
}

let userToken = await AuthUser(data)
console.log(userToken) // your data
```

Comment: You don't need the `.then(token => return token)`, that's just an unnecessary passthrough.  Simply return the the google login call.

Comment: For ES8 / Nodejs, errors are thrown if you use `await` outside of an async function. Perhaps the better example here would be to make the `AuthUser` function `async`, that then ends with `return await google.login(...);`

Comment: This worked for me and is a simpler solution imo. Don't forget to use async.

Comment: It gives me this error ``` let answer =  await getAnswer(url);
               ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules```

Comment: @AnshumanKumar try like this: `const AuthUser = async(data) => { await google.login(data.username, data.password)}`

Answer (score 6):

If that situation happens for a multiple values like an array.

```sh
[ 
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> },
  Promise { <pending> }
]
```

You can use `Promise.all()` this will resolve all promises.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 5):

The `then` method returns a pending promise which can be resolved asynchronously by the return value of a result handler registered in the call to `then`, or rejected by throwing an error inside the handler called.

So calling `AuthUser` will not suddenly log the user in synchronously, but returns a promise whose then registered handlers will be called after the login succeeds ( or fails). I would suggest triggering all login processing by a `then` clause of the login promise. E.G. using named functions to highlight the sequence of flow:

```
let AuthUser = data => {   // just the login promise
  return google.login(data.username, data.password);
};

AuthUser(data).then( processLogin).catch(loginFail);

function processLogin( token) {
      // do logged in stuff:
      // enable, initiate, or do things after login
}
function loginFail( err) {
      console.log("login failed: " + err);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the MDN section on [Promises.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) In particular, look at the return type of [then().](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)

To log in, the user-agent has to submit a request to the server and wait to receive a response. Since making your application totally stop execution during a request round-trip usually makes for a bad user experience, practically every JS function that logs you in (or performs any other form of server interaction) will use a Promise, or something very much like it, to deliver results asynchronously.

Now, also notice that `return` statements are always evaluated in the context of the function they appear in. So when you wrote:

```
let AuthUser = data => {
  return google
    .login(data.username, data.password)
    .then( token => {
      return token;
    });
};
```

the statement `return token;` meant that the anonymous function being passed into `then()` should return the token, not that the `AuthUser` function should. What `AuthUser` returns is the result of calling `google.login(username, password).then(callback);`, which happens to be a Promise.

Ultimately your callback `token => { return token; }` does nothing; instead, your input to `then()` needs to be a function that actually handles the token in some way.

Comment: @Src I wrote my answer before the asker clarified that they were looking for a way to *synchronously* return a value, and without making assumptions about their dev environment or language version beyond what could be inferred by the code snippet -- that is, it's safe to assume ES6, but not necessarily ES7.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh All right, will do. I'm assuming the problem is that I've misunderstood how `return` is treated with the new(ish) closure syntax, in which case -- well, I strongly disapprove of that, but the error is still mine and I apologize for it.

Comment: i can understand how you feel as return should be sync, and it should return control to its caller, which is an anonymous function. but the explanation for you is that you should note that the return type of then() is a new Promise object, hence the value returned by the callback is used to fulfill or reject the promise. But, if the callback returns another Promise, then the new Promise (the one returned by then()) will be fulfilled only when this Promise fulfills.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh Er, I actually did know that part, which is why I asserted that `token => { return token; }` *does nothing* as opposed to claiming it was counterproductive. You can say `google.login(username, password).then(token=>{return token;}).then(token=>{return token;})` and so forth forever, but you'll only achieve returning a `Promise` that resolves with a token—same as if you just left it as `google.login(username, password);`. I'm not sure why you feel that this is "very wrong".

Comment: @AhmadBamieh: can you be more specific about what is wrong in this piece of text? I don't see anything, he just explains why `return token` doesn't work as the OP probably expected.

Comment: @Bergi I updated my answer in this post to contain full details about the issue, comment section is way too small for code writing. please read it here http://stackoverflow.com/a/38884856/5384679

Comment: @AhmadBamieh: there is indeed a misunderstanding. We all three know well how promises work, the statement is that `promise.then(result => { return result; })` is exactly equivalent to `promise`, therefore the method call *does nothing* and should be dropped to simplify the code and enhance readability - a statement that is completely true.

Comment: @bergi aha, okay i understand your point now. this is correct

Answer (score 0):

Your **Promise** is pending, complete it by

```
userToken.then(function(result){
console.log(result)
})
```

after your remaining code.
All this code does is that `.then()` completes your promise & captures the end result in **result** variable & print result in console.
Keep in mind, you cannot store the result in global variable.
Hope that explanation might help you.

Comment: Is the console log necessary? What about if you insert debugger? That seems to change behaviour.

Comment: @mathtick I assume the `console.log` is for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue earlier, but my situation was a bit different in the front-end. I'll share my scenario anyway, maybe someone might find it useful.

I had an api call to `/api/user/register` in the frontend with email, password and username as request body. On submitting the form(register form), a handler function is called which initiates the fetch call to `/api/user/register`. I used the `event.preventDefault()` in the beginning line of this handler function, all other lines,like forming the request body as well the fetch call was written after the `event.preventDefault()`. This returned a `pending promise`.

But when I put the request body formation code above the `event.preventDefault()`,  it returned the real promise. Like this:

```
event.preventDefault();
    const data = {
        'email': email,
        'password': password
    }
    fetch(...)
     ...
```

instead of :

```
     const data = {
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        }
     event.preventDefault();
     fetch(...)
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
var number1 = document.getElementById("number1");
var number2 = document.getElementById("number2");
startAsync.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (number1.value > 0 && number2.value > 0) {
        asyncTest(parseInt(number1.value), parseInt(number2.value)).then(function(result) {
            document.getElementById("promiseResolved").textContent = "promiseResolved: " + result
        });
    } else {
        asyncTest(1, 2).then(function(result) {
            document.getElementById("promiseResolved").textContent = "promiseResolved: " + result
        });
    }

});

async function asyncTest(a, b) {
    return await (a + b);
};
```

```html
  <button id="startAsync">start Async function</button><br />
  <input type="number" id="number1" /><br />
  <input type="number" id="number2" /><br />
  <span id="promiseResolved"></span><br />
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, however this would be more useful if you added an explanation of how your solution works and why this is better/ how it compares to solutions already offered.

Answer (score 0):

Im my case (JS) I forgot to add **await**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).