# How to resolve this promise correctly in order to get the image data url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I'm using this code in chrome and firefox console

```
let m=$.getScript("https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js", function() {
html2canvas(document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > img"), {
            onrendered: function(canvas) {
                 var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
        return myImage;
               },
                       allowTaint: true,
                    taintTest: false
         });
         }); 


m.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    window.open(value);
});
```

but i'm getting the following

[image: please check the image]

I've checked these answers:

[Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

*Appreciate any help !*

Comment: The complete callback is not part of the promise chain. Consider just passing a function reference to `onrendered` and consume the url there

Comment: You have nowhere to `return` to in `onrendered`. Could also just call a function that has the url as argument

Comment: @charlietfl can you please provide an edited code ?

Comment: @charlietfl i don't have big knowledge in js, i will inject the code in android webview
i tried for many hours but nothing worked, i just want to get the data url of the current shown captcha, the only code works, gives me another captcha

Answer (score -1):

You could just pass a function reference to `onrendered` and do whatever you need to with the resultant url there

```
function onCanvasRender(canvas) {
  var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
  console.log(myImage);
}


$.getScript("https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/dist/html2canvas.js", function() {
  html2canvas(document.querySelector("body > table.troisbords > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div > blockquote > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > img"), {
    onrendered: onCanvasRender,
    allowTaint: true,
    taintTest: false
  });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, but i'm getting `{readyState: 1, setRequestHeader: ƒ, getAllResponseHeaders: ƒ, getResponseHeader: ƒ, overrideMimeType: ƒ, …}` in chrome and firefox console, i use them to test the script in the website before i put it in my android app

Comment: That's the xhr object. Not sure how you ever got that

Comment: did you test it in your side in chrome or firefox ?
this is the website https://www4.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/AuthentificationEtud?ident=cin

Comment: That's a jqXHR object, not an XHR object and it's the return value of `$.getScript()`

Comment: @MinusFour so what to change in the code in order to get the right captcha data url ?