# How can i resolve the promise correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, promise, html2canvas

I have this code

```
let img= html2canvas($("#divPage")[0], {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        var myImage = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");                                              
        return myImage;
    },    
    allowTaint: true,
    taintTest: false
});
img.then((value) => {
    console.log(value);
    window.open(value);
});
```

`window.open(value);` open a new tab with the link https://www1.inscription.tn/ORegMx/servlet/[object%20HTMLCanvasElement]

so the problem is `let img` is in the wrong place, it let the method return the object which is the HTMLCanvasElement instead of returning the image data url returned from `onrendered: function(canvas)`

I've checked these answers:

[Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise {  } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

How can i fix that in order to get the correct value ?

Hope someone can help,

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like the promise doesn't resolve with the return value of the `onrendered` callback. Why not just drop that and use the `value.toDataURL()` in the `then` callback?

Comment: @Bergi can you share a code with that suggestion please
i'm getting an error `TypeError: html2canvas(...).then is not a function`

Comment: But that is what your current code was doing as well (`img` being the promise)?

Comment: It would seem that `html2canvas()` is designed to be used with its `onrendered` option *or*  the `then()` method of the returned promise. Both expose the same `canvas` element to a callback function. Try using one approach or the other, not both.