# Function value returning Promise Pending

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Can someone help me why my code below is returning Promise pending value for out variable?

```
var out = dbConn.connect().then(function (){
        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
        request.input("terminalId", sql.VarChar, terminalID).query("SELECT terminalContextKey from device_context where terminalId = @terminalId").then(function (result, recordSet) {
            dbConn.close();
            finalterminalkey = result.recordset[0].terminalContextKey;
            console.dir(JSON.stringify(finalterminalkey));
            Promise.resolve(recordSet);
            return JSON.stringify(finalterminalkey);


        }).catch(function (err) {
            console.log(err);
            dbConn.close();
        });

    }).catch(function (err) {
       console.log(err);
    });

    console.dir(out);
   return out;
```

Comment: This is too broad for us. "why does my code do X" questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow without research.

Comment: @zix Normally I would not change between code formatting types, but I suppose it's because of the 6 char limit in this case.

Comment: Anything returned from within `.then()` will result in a new promise. Assign `JSON.stringify(finalterminalkey)` to a variable in global scope instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)  (assuming you're not asking why it isn't a promise-resolved)

Comment: I tried assigning to global variable, but it is returning what I assigned as. suppose null or ""

Comment: @shivanara: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call for additional explanation of why that is, but in general you just need to understand the concept of asynchronicity.

Answer (score 2):

A JavaScript `Promise` is like a real-life promise. Let me make an example:

> `Person A` promises `Person B` to get milk from the store.

Now `Person A` has to wait for `Person B` to get the milk. `Person A` doesn't know when the milk will be there, or maybe the milk will never arrive.

The same goes for JavaScript `Promises`. They will eventually resolve, but they can also throw an error. In that case the code that you put into the `catch()` will be used to "catch" the error.  If they resolve, they will run the code in `then()`.

Your variable `out` is a promise. You have to put your logic in `then()` or `catch()`.

When you return `out`, JavaScript doesn't know if the `Promise` is already ready/resolved.

Comment: I will accept the answer. almost close enough. could you point out what I am doing worng?

Comment: {
var out = dbConn.connect().then(function (){
        var request = new sql.Request(dbConn);
        request.input("terminalId", sql.VarChar, terminalID).query("SELECT terminalContextKey from device_context where terminalId = @terminalId")
        .then(function (out, err) {
            dbConn.close();
            finalterminalkey = out.recordset[0].terminalContextKey;
            //console.dir(JSON.stringify(finalterminalkey));
            
        })
        
    });
    
    return out;
}

Answer (score 1):

`.then` and `.catch` both return references to a new promise. This is why you can chain them. Because you are probably logging the Promise right after calling it, it hasn't resolved yet and is still pending. [This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) is a good resource on how exactly Promises work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `.then` and `.catch` statements, but they return a new promise instead of the original promise. Still, they would be good. You can check the duplicate for more references. When you use `out`, the promise is not resolved yet so still, if you use the `.then` statement which is when the promise is resolved and `.catch` which is when the promise fails.