# Firebase Cloud Firestore query returning Promise { <pending> } instead of fulfilled when using async/await

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, promise, es6-promise

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val) is similar but didn't help.

The goal is to use async/await with Firebase Cloud Firestore queries instead of the then/catch Promise code from [the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

However, the function below rejects successfully in the negative case, but returns `Promise { <pending> }` instead of the Cloud Firestore doc.

```
async getUser(emailAddress) {
    // Return null if @emailAddress blank.
    if (!emailAddress) {
        return null;
    }

    // Assume @db points to a Cloud Firestore database. Query only returns one doc.
    let query = db.collection('users').where('emailAddress', '==', emailAddress);
    try {
        let querySnapshot = await query.get();
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
           return doc.data();               
        });
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error getting user: ', e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `emailAddress` is not null or undefined, your function returns nothing because[`forEach()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#foreach) returns void.

Since you have only one doc in the `querySnapshot` you can do as follows:

```
async getUser(emailAddress) {
    // Return null if @emailAddress blank.
    if (!emailAddress) {
        return null;
    }

    // Assume @db points to a Cloud Firestore database. Query only returns one doc.
    const query = db.collection('users').where('emailAddress', '==', emailAddress);
    try {
        const querySnapshot = await query.get();
        return querySnapshot.docs[0].data();               
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error getting user: ', e);
    }
}
```

Note that your `getUser()` function is itself asynchronous, so you need to use `then()` (or async/await) to get the doc value when the Promise it returns is fulfilled.

```
const emailAddress = "john@gmail.com";
getUser(emailAddress).
then(userData => { ... })
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to return from `forEach`, but `forEach` doesn't return anything, rather it loops through elements and allows you to modify them.

You can modify your code like this for example:

```js
async getUser(emailAddress) {
    // Return null if @emailAddress blank.
    if (!emailAddress) {
        return null;
    }

    // Assume @db points to a Cloud Firestore database. Query only returns one doc.
    let query = db.collection('users').where('emailAddress', '==', emailAddress);
    try {
        const results = [];
        let querySnapshot = await query.get();
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
           results.push(doc.data());               
        });
        return results;
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('Error getting user: ', e);
    }
}
```

More info about [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

> forEach() executes the callback function once for each array element;
> unlike map() or reduce() it always returns the value undefined and is
> not chainable. The typical use case is to execute side effects at the
> end of a chain.

Answer (score 2):

`async` functions, such as yours, **always** return a promise.  That can't be avoided.  All of the asynchronous behavior is still there in the function, and the caller still has to `await` or `then` to get the value in the promise.  You can't use async/await to remove a promise and return immediately.

On top of that, your function doesn't actually return any documents.  The return inside the `forEach` is actually just returning from the inline lambda function that you passed to `forEach`.  That return doesn't extend to the enclosing `getUser` function.

If you want to use async/await effectively, the function still has to return a value from its top level.  And the caller still has to use await or then to get the value out of the returned promise.