# node.js function returns Promise { <pending> }, why?

Tags: node.js, async-await

I'm beginner in nodejs, This function returns "Promise {pending}
"  I Appreciate any help.
Thanks

```
async function getCurrentUser(id){
try{
    let user = User.findOne({id:id})
    return user;

}catch(err){
    return err;
}     
}
```

Comment: await missing??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Comment: where should I place the await?

Comment: All `async` function return a promise - always.  The caller must use `.then()` or `await` on that promise to get the value out of the promise.  You can NEVER directly return a value from the function that was obtained asynchronously in Javascript.    It cannot be done. Once it is asynchronous, all callers that want access to the value must use asynchronous means for getting access to the value. That's how asynchronous stuff works in Javascript.  `await` can make some things easier, but even if you `await User.findOne()`, the caller of `getCurrentUser()` will STILL have to `.then()` or `await`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missing the `await` in front of some function that return a `Promise`

```js
 let user = await User.findOne({id:id})
```

`Promise` is an immutable async operation that need time to finish so you either use `async/await` like you did or chain the `promise` with `.then` call like

```js
User.findOne({ id })
.then((response) => {
  // do sth with the resposne
});
```

recommend you to read [Async & Performance](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/1st-ed/async%20%26%20performance) from `YDKJS` series

full rewrite of code:

```js
async function getCurrentUser(id) {
    try {
        let user = await User.findOne({ id: id })
        return user;

    } catch (err) {
        return err;
    }
}

//  getCurrentUser usage

async function doSth(){
    let user = await getCurrentUser();
}
```

usage clarification:

putting `async` in front of a function make this function return type a promise no matter what you return inside it so the only two way to use such a function is just like how you use a `promise` either use it in another `async` function using `await` or use `.then()` chaining function

Comment: thanks for your time but it still returns Promise { <pending> }, :) would you please write the full function?

Answer (score 2):

u missing await

```js
async function getCurrentUser(id){
try{
    let user = await User.findOne({id:id})
    return user;

}catch(err){
    return err;
}
```