# Promise is "pending" even with having ".then" chained, issues only occurs while using normal functions

Tags: javascript, promise, fetch

I am currently trying to use an API to get IP addresses for visitors. I am getting a "promise pending" message when using the following code:

```
function getIPAdd(){
  var ip = fetch('https://pro.ip-api.com/json/?key=KEY').then(response => response.json()).then(data => data);
  return ip;
}
var ipAdd = getIPAdd();
console.log(ipAdd);
```

I get this output:

```
Promise {<pending>}
   __proto__: Promise
   [[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
   [[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

This means that the promise is ebing fulfilled but for some reason, still is not completed?

While if I use the following code:

```
(function(){
   fetch('https://pro.ip-api.com/json/?key=KEY').then(response => response.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
 })();
```

I do not get any "promise pending" issues. I am guessing this is becasue it is due to the way `console.log` is used in the latter code sample but how can I fix the first code sample so I get my JSON output the way I need it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Comment: You have a timing problem. What you fail to realize is that the function inside `then` is only called after the fetch completes but `return ip` gets executed first before the function inside `then`. The `then` methon **is** how you are supposed to return a value

Comment: You can just do `var ipadd = getIpAdd(); ipadd.then(console.log)`

Comment: Or you can do `async function x () { var ipadd = await getIpAdd(); console.log(ipadd) } ; x()`

Comment: Okay, that works! But how would I use this if I wanted the JSON value to be returned from the function itself? As in, without having to do all the extra ".then" outside the function

Comment: If you don't want to use `.then`s you can use `await`, but that is only possible inside an `async` function. (And this async function itself will then return a Promise.) You can't fully synchronize asynchronous code.

Comment: I got it. Thank you, I will use that then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to resolve the promise that `fetch` returns. Something like this should work:

```
function getIPAdd(){
  var ip = fetch('https://pro.ip-api.com/json/?key=KEY').then(response => response.json());
  return ip;
}
var ipAdd = getIPAdd();
ipAdd.then(data => console.log(data));
```

Another way to do this is by using the `await` keyword. The only catch there is that you can only do so from an `async` function. So here is an example:

```
const getIP = () => fetch('https://pro.ip-api.com/json/?key=KEY').then(response => response.json())

const main = async () => {
  ip = await getIP();
  console.log(ip)
}

main();
```

Answer (score 1):

This happens because at the time of your `console.log` the Promises haven't been resolved yet, in other words, `console.log(ipAdd)` runs **before** `return ip`.
Fixing this with promises can get complicated, I recommend using the async/await and ES6+ syntax:

```js
const getIPAdd = async () => {
  const response = await fetch('https://pro.ip-api.com/json/?key=KEY');
  const ip = await response.json();
  return ip;
}

const doStuffWithIP = async () => {
  const ipAdd = await getIpAdd()
  console.log(ipAdd)
  // Code to use IP address here
}

doStuffWithIP() // Don't forget to call the function
```