# How in React do I return a number?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In react all I want to do is lookup and return a number. I have:

```
  getVAL = async ()  => {
    const pathParam = this.props.match.params.myVal;
    const url = "get-myVal?myVal=" + pathParam;
    const response = await this._axios.get(url);
    const intmyVal = Number(response.data);
    return   Number (intmyVal)
  };
```

and I use this:

```
 myVal=this.getVAL();
```

but when I render...

```
  myVal={this.myVal}
```

I get `Type 'Promise<number>' is not assignable to type 'number'.` Completely new to this weird world, so any pointers are appreciated.

EDIT: With jonrsharpe's help (any mistakes, mine) I now have:

```
myIdPromise=this.getID();

myIdPromise.then(don't know what to put here to just get a number {
   ...
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Comment: You're getting the compile time equivalent, but the compiler's telling you the right thing.

Comment: Please try to use parseInt()

Comment: Surely you can say in React I want a number from an async method?

Comment: `async` functions **always** return promises - _in JavaScript_, not just React or TypeScript.

Comment: OK, sorry to doubt you. So `.then` is needed somehow or other? Where might it go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked:

```
async getIDPromise(): Promise<Number> {
...
  return   intmyVal
}

async getID(): Promise<Number> {

  const value = await this.getIDPromise()
```