# How can I use the return of an async function as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, async-await, axios

I have this function

```
const totalJueces = async(id, idPost) => {
  try{
       const res = await axios(`${process.env.REACT_APP_PJUD_URLBASE}agenda/fullList/${id}/${idPost}`, { 'timeout': 30000 })
       console.log(res.data.listaJuecesAsignadosCausa.length)
  }
  catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

If I `console.log(res.data.listaJuecesAsignadosCausa.length)` it's actually giving me the correct response, in this case an integer (I need to know the specific number of arrays in that request)

But If I try to use this function with a return, it returns a Promise pending.

How can I use the correct number to use it as a dynamic parameter in a loop of items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Promises will always log pending as long as the results are not resolved yet. You must call `.then` on the promise, or alternatively, `await` the promise, to capture the results regardless of the promise state (resolved or still pending).

see [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Comment: Instead of answering, you can just vote to close the question as a duplicate of the question you ask them to "see"...

Comment: Oh actually I had already tried that. totalJueces(blockData.crrCausa, blockData.idBloqueAgenda).then(x => console.log(x))  and the console.log it's working fine. But lets say I return the x, it's still a promise. But I'll look more into it, thanks!