# promise is fulfilled but the result is undefined

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, promise

I have a promise and the `console.log` inside of the promise gives me a string, but I cant use the result outside of the promise as the result is `undefined`.

```
   const docId = firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('payments')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id);
            return doc.id;
        });
    });

console.log(docId);
```

So `console.log(doc.id)` return a value, but I can't get the result and use it outside of the `const docId`. Is there a way to grab the result of `doc.id` and use it outside of the `const docId`?

Comment: promises are asynchronous - you're console.log runs before the firestore stuff even starts

Comment: @Bravo furthermore, the final `then` doesn't have a return value, so the promise chain will produce `undefined` in the end anyway.

Comment: Bravo and VLAZ are correct. You can learn how to use promises here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: you should return data from `.then` statement, something like: `return querySnapshot.map(doc => doc.id)`, in such case docId will be an array of ids

Comment: Also `forEach` returns nothing..

Comment: Also [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're never returning a value in the final `.then` statement. One way to use the value outside the promise is to use a variable defined outside the promise, or you could use `await` as so:

```js
// If you're in an async function you can use await to get the result of the promise
const docId = await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection('users')
    .doc(user.uid)
    .collection('payments')
    .get()
    .then(querySnapshot => {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id);
            return doc.id; // The return here does nothing
        });
        // You need to return something here
        return querySnapshot[0].id;
    });

console.log(docId);
```

Comment: You might want to also mention you will need this inside a an `async` function.