# object Promise showing instead of data pulled from API call

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to get data from an opensea api and display the return part name from it in the front end.

this is my function to get the api call which works 100% fine

```
async function getData(url){
var _data;
 let response = await fetch(url);
 let data = await response.json();  
 _data = [data.name, data.id];
 console.log(_data);
 return _data[0];
```

This log to console shows what i want it to[image]

However when i try make it display on the front end here

```
 options = getData('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/');
```

using {{options}} to get the data and display it temporarily until it works

it shows this

[image]

where the [object Promise] should show [cryptopunk #1, 158831]

Anyone have an idea of what i am doing wrong

the options = getdata() is inside the class and the async function above the @component

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val) | [async/await implicitly returns promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35302431) | [How to access the value of a promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29516390) | [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Comment: No it sadly doesnt i have tried that but i cannot await a call from the class because you cant async the whole class in order to use an await

Comment: 1. Classes can have `async` methods. So, it's definitely possible to use `await` from a class. 2. You can always use `.then()` instead. Whatever your choice, you have an asynchronous piece of code - you *cannot* convert it to synchronous one.

Comment: export class SharestableComponent implements OnInit {
in this peice of code for my class how would i turn this into an async one

Comment: You don't make *the class* async. The *methods* can be async.

Comment: Thats what i have done in the code above am i not correct? when calling the method if i put await in front of the call it says i cant do that in the class export thing and i should at the top of the module, but then i wouldnt be able to access it inside the front end

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
getData('https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/asset/0xb47e3cd837ddf8e4c57f05d70ab865de6e193bbb/1/').then(data=>{
console.log(data);
})
```

This is working properly

```js
async function getData(url){
  var _data;
  let response = await fetch(url);
  console.log(response);
  return response;
 }
 
 getData('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1').then(option=>{
 console.log(option)
 })
```

Comment: but saving getData to a variable and then using that variable as {{variable}} in the angular html displays it as [object Promise] still

Comment: Nevermind i did this in a different way and it worked, your a genius and thanks x