# Console.log() executing before function in Javascript - Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, function, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm trying to learn to use Puppeteer in Javascript, but I seem to have some issues related to Javascript and its asynchronous functions, here is my code:

```
function crearEquipos() {
   const campeones = obtenerCampeones();
   console.log(campeones)
}

crearEquipos();
```

The problem is that in the function "crearEquipos()" I want to log the variable "campeones", but the console.log executes before the function "obtenerCampeones()" which should get its value, so the log ends up being:

```
Promise { undefined }
```

I think this has to do with asynchronous functions, I still don't understand them well, so I'm not sure how to solve this issue.
Any explanation is welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Answer (score 0):

```
const crearEquipos = async () => {
  const campeones = await obtenerCampeones();
  console.log(campeones)
}
crearEquipos()
```