# How to resolve an asynchronous function when returning a hoisted array?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to return `describedIpList` after all async operations are resolved.
I can see a few ways to solve this without a promise, but I am interested in learning how to do this in best practice with a promise, do I really have to wrap another promise around my function and if so, please show me how to do this correctly.

```
 const ipResolver = (ips) => {
    const describedIpList = [];

    ips.map((ip) => {
        Promise.all([
            client.country(ip),
            client.city(ip)
        ])
            .then(response => {
                [Country, City] = response;
                describedIpList.push({
                    ip,
                    countryCode: Country.country.isoCode,
                    postalCode: City.postal.code,
                    cityName: City.city.names.en,
                    timeZone: City.location.timeZone,
                    accuracyRadius: City.location.accuracyRadius,
                });
                console.log(describedIpList);
            })
            .catch(err => describedIpList.push({ip, error: err.error}));
        return describedIpList;

    });
```

To reiterate. I am looking to return `describedIpList` after `ips.map()` resolves and then return a response `res.json({fullyDescribedIps: ipResolver(ips)});`

Answer (score 0):

You'll need two `Promise.all`s - one to wait for all ip requests to resolve, and one to wait for the country and city of all of those to resolve.

```
const ipResolver = ips => Promise.all(
    ips.map(ip => Promise.all([
        client.country(ip),
        client.city(ip)
    ])
        .then(([Country, City]) => ({
            ip,
            countryCode: Country.country.isoCode,
            postalCode: City.postal.code,
            cityName: City.city.names.en,
            timeZone: City.location.timeZone,
            accuracyRadius: City.location.accuracyRadius,
        }))
        .catch(err => ({ ip, error: err.error }))
    )
);
```

Comment: Why not just `Promise.resolve`? For the outer Promise

Comment: That wouldn't result in a Promise that resolves with the array of values - that'd result in an array of Promises that the consumer if `ipResolver` would then have to call `Promise.all` on to get to a useable result. Better to put it inside the function.

Comment: Ah, good point.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CertainPerformance, the function is returning an empty array (should return items), I'm assuming something is amiss with the promise there. Will you be editing this for an accepted answer by any chance?

Comment: @clusterBuddy There is no way that the code in my answer returns an empty array if the parameter array has any values - can you double check that you're using my code exactly? Runnable snippet with dummied up data: https://jsfiddle.net/51ohg3fq/

Comment: @clusterBuddy As you can see, the Promise that gets returned doesn't resolve to an empty array

Comment: I just reverted back to my old function and printed to console in the `then()`, for sure it's supposed to return 3 objects. went back to your functions and `res.json({fullyDescribedIps: ipResolver(ips)});` returns `fullyDescribedIps:{}`

Comment: `ipResolver` returns a Promise, not the value the Promise resolves to. You must wait for the Promise to resolve, which is done with `.then`. You must do that before calling `res.json`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/38884522

Comment: @CertainPerformance - you are right, resolved the route response like this: `ipResolver(ips).then(describedIps => res.json(describedIps)` looks a bit wonky resolving a route from a promise resolve, but works. If you have a better way of executing this to resolve from an endpoint, would be happy.

Comment: @clusterBuddy Looks perfectly normal to me - that's a very typical-looking sort of route when you need to perform something asynchronous before sending, don't worry about how the syntax looks.

Comment: @clusterBuddy When in this sort of situation, but the `this` of the callback doesn't matter, you could simplify `fn.then(res => obj.cb(res))` to just `fn.then(obj.cb)` - but with Express, it does depend on having a calling context of the response, so there's no way to remove the inline callback here

Answer (score 0):

```js
async function ipInfo(ip) {
  try {
    const [Country, City] = await Promise.all([
      client.country(ip),
      client.city(ip),
    ]);
    // const [Country, City] = await client.countryAndCity(ip);
    return {
      ip,
      countryCode: Country.country.isoCode,
      postalCode: City.postal.code,
      cityName: City.city.names.en,
      timeZone: City.location.timeZone,
      accuracyRadius: City.location.accuracyRadius,
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return { ip, error: err.error };
  }
}

const ipResolver = Promise.all(ips.map(ipInfo));
// const ipsInfo = await Promise.all(ips.map(ipInfo));
```