# Why i am getting Promise { <pending> } while calling a function from EJS file in node.js

Tags: node.js

Below is my function to return SQL query result.

```
function getPriorityList(operatorId) {
      try {
        const result = Api.getApisDetail(operatorId);
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Answer (score 0):

you should wait for promise fulfillment

try this :

```js
async function getPriorityList(operatorId) {
      try {
        const result = await Api.getApisDetail(operatorId);
        return result;
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
```

Comment: This has been answered many times before, please flag questions like these as duplicate instead of posting answers to them, SO should not have tons of different versions of basically the same question, all with slightly different answers, as this makes it hard to keep all relevant information updated and consolidated.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the promise implementation is incorrect in this case. Try something along these lines:

```
function getPriorityList(operatorId) {
    Api.getApisDetail(operatorId).then((result) =>{
        console.log(result);
        return result;
    }).catch((error)=>{
        return error;
    });
}
```

The "Api.getApisDetail" function must also return promise in this case.

Comment: i can console the result but getting undifined, in ejs file from where this function was called.

Comment: post more information. like what's there in ejs file and how u have implemented "Api.getApisDetail" function

Comment: from ejs file i am calling this function <h1><% var result = ejsHelper.getPriorityList(rows.id); %></h1>
                                            <% console.log(result); %>