# document.cookie showing inconsistent length

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making a `create-react-app` that stores an access token within `document.cookie` to handle login / accessing protected routes.

My main component, `App.js` has a function `isLoggedIn()`:

```
    async isLoggedIn() {
        if (document.cookie !== '') {
            // Check for existence of `token` cookie
            let cookies = parseCookies(document.cookie);
            if (cookies.token) {
                try {
                    let payload = await BackendService.verifyToken(cookies.token);
                    this.setState({
                        'name': payload.name,
                        'email': payload.email
                    });
                    return payload.valid || false;
                } catch (err) {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                console.log('No token cookie found.')
                return false;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I pass this function as a prop to children to allow them to check login status:

```
<TopBar isLoggedIn={this.isLoggedIn} />
```

Within TopBar is where I conditionally render based on `isLoggedIn()`:

```
                        { this.props.isLoggedIn() &&
                            <li className="nav-item">Welcome <a href="#account">{this.props.name}</a></li>
                        }
                        { !this.props.isLoggedIn() &&
                            <li className="navItem"><a href="#login" onClick={this.showModal}>Sign In</a></li>
                        }
```

However, when `document.cookie` is empty (deleted cookies through Application tab of Dev Tools), `Welcome` is rendered rather than the `Sign In`.

If I try to log the value of `this.props.isLoggedIn()` from within `TopBar`, instead of a boolean being printed, a Promise is printed? Which doesn't make sense to me. Sure `async` keyword on `isLoggedIn()` indicates a function *could* be returned, but I am explicitly returning a boolean at each stage of the control flow, so I am unsure how a promise is ever involved.

The only way I could see a promise being returned is because of the `BackendService.verifyToken()` function, but that is using `await` anyways and so shouldn't return a promise. Also a promise shouldn't be returned anyways if I immediately exit the function with `false`, right?

I have looked at [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val), however like I said above, using the `await` keyword should be enough to return a value and not a promise.

Comment: It looks as though you aren't awaiting the promise anywhere? So `this.props.isLoggedIn()` at render is just a promise, so always truthy

Comment: `let payload = await BackendService.verifyToken(cookies.token);`
That's the only asynchronous operation happening

Comment: sure - but regardless, you'll be returning a promise. So when the render code evaluates `this.props.isLoggedIn()`, it'll get a promise, not a boolean.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of the `await` keyword to indicate I want to wait for the asychronous operation to finish rather than dealing with promises?

Comment: I think that's maybe the part which is causing the confusion - if you define a function as `async` it'll always return a promise.

Answer (score 0):

You're using a promise directly in the render rather than the actual boolean that you expect. Once you define a function as `async`, it'll always return a promise. Consider this code:

```
import React from "react";

const C1 = ({ isLoggedIn }) => (
  <div>I am{isLoggedIn() ? " " : " not "}logged in</div>
);
const C2 = ({ isLoggedIn }) => {
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    isLoggedIn().then(setLoggedIn);
  }, [isLoggedIn]);

  return <div>I am{loggedIn ? " " : " not "}logged in</div>;
};

export default function App() {
  const isLoggedIn = async () => {
    console.log("Running check");
    return false;
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <C1 isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
      <C2 isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

`C1` will render "I am logged in".
`C2` will render "I am not logged in".

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it in a different way, since I am using Components and not Hooks:

Within my `TopBar` component, I use the `componentDidMount()` lifecycle hook:

```
async componentDidMount() {
    let result = await this.props.isLoggedIn();
    this.setState({'login' : result});
}
```

Then simply conditionally render based on `state.login`:

```
{ this.state.login &&
```