# How I save response from axios.post to a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

```
const axios = require('axios');

const RequestLogin = async function () {

    let auth = {
        "user_name": "username12l",
        "password": "password12l",
    };

    let res = await axios.post('https://.../api/v1/login', auth);
    //console.log("Dentro da Funcao", res);
    return await res;
}
const login = RequestLogin()

console.log("loginSysaidCookie -> ", RequestLogin)
console.log("Login -> ", login)
```

How do I send the data to the const login?

My console --->

`loginSysaidCookie ->  [AsyncFunction: loginSysaidCookie]`
`login ->  Promise { <pedings> }`

I want the constant login to get the RequestLogin response.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my asynchronous function returning Promise { <pending> } instead of a value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38884522/why-is-my-asynchronous-function-returning-promise-pending-instead-of-a-val)

Answer (score 0):

### Using the `await` keyword

Like this:

```
const login = await RequestLogin();
```

Explanation:
Because the function is asynchronous, it allows other processes to run even if it's not finished running. You can add the `await` keyword to tell javascript to wait for the function to finish running before continuing on.

**Catch: Can't be used on the top level (only in functions, etc)**

### Using `.then()` and `.catch()`

Using `.then()` and `.catch()` allow for top-level use. `.then()` must be added following the function and then you can add a function in the `.then()` which will run what you want to run after the main function runs. `.catch()` also allows a function as an argument which runs when an error is returned.

Example:

```
async function fetchFromDatabase() {
    ...
}

fetchFromDatabase.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error: ", error)
})
```

Comment: const login = await RequestLogin()
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

Comment: You can also use .then().catch() instead of await, but I find await much cleaner for most situations.

Comment: @EdsonLuizdosSantosJunior You also must have the function in an async function. Then you can call that function at the top level. I think you can use .then().catch() on the top level though.

Comment: @EdsonLuizdosSantosJunior I edited my answer to be more thorough, hopefully, it helps!

Comment: thanks for your help but do you know how can get the res or err and send it to a variable?

Comment: @EdsonLuizdosSantosJunior You can initialize the variable with let (maybe have a default value like undefined or something) and then change the variable once fetched. 

You can even have all future code inside the .then() function.